# MYSQL // Performance of "DISTINCT" drops around 100000 entries when recucing the amount of distinct entries

Tags: python, mysql, performance, distinct

We are dealing with some performance issues upon inserting the DISTINCT command in our SQL-queries.
The problem occurs only in the following scenario: 100000 entries (or more) with only ~1% (or less) of distinct values in them.

We boiled down the issue to the following minimal python example (but it's not related to python, mysql workbench behaves the same):

```
import mysql.connector
import time
import numpy as np

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password', host='server',
                                            database='database', raise_on_warnings=True, autocommit=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#define amount of entries
max_exponent = 4.7
n_entry = 10**max_exponent

# fill table with 10, 100, ... distinct entries
for n_distinct in np.logspace(1, max_exponent, num=int(max_exponent)):

    # Dropping BENCHMARK table if already exists and create new one
    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BENCHMARK")
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE BENCHMARK(ID INT)')

    # create distinct number set and insert random permutation of it into table
    distinct_numbers = range(int(n_distinct))
    random_numbers = np.random.randint(len(distinct_numbers), size=int(n_entry))
    value_string = ','.join([f"({i_name})" for i_name in random_numbers])
    mySql_insert_query = f"INSERT INTO BENCHMARK (ID) VALUES {value_string}"

    print(f'filling table with {n_entry:.0f} random values of {n_distinct:.0f} distinct numbers')
    cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
    conn.commit()

    # benchmark distinct call
    start = time.time()
    sql_query = 'SELECT DISTINCT ID from BENCHMARK'
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(f'Time to read {len(result)} distinct values: {time.time()-start:.2f}')

conn.close()
```

The extracted benchmark times show a counter-intuitive behaviour, where time suddenly increases for fewer distinct values in the table:

[image]

If we make the query without using DISTINCT the times drop to 170ms, independent from amount of distinct entries.
We cannot make any sense of this dependence (except for some "hardware limitation", but 100000 entries should be ... negligible?), so we ask you for insight what the root cause of this behaviour might be.

The machine we are using for the database has the following specs:

- CPU: Intel i5 @ 3.3GHz (CPU Load goes to 30% during execution)
- Ram: 8 GB (mysqld takes about 2.4GB, does not rise during query execution, InnoDB Buffer usage stays at 42%, buffer_size = 4GB)
- HDD: 500GB, ~90% empty
- OS, Mysql: Windows 10, Mysql Server 8.0.18

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is there any `index` over the `id` column?

Comment: First point: proper benchmarking is more difficult than it might seem. For example, running the benchmark process on the same node as the benchmarked process can influence the result if both processes start competing for resources (and CPU is not the only limited resource). Also, properly measuring the time _really_ spent is not as simple as checking the system clock before and after - if the system's scheduler switches during this time (to the benchmarked process for example xD), then you are measuring time spent elsewhere too.

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN` on your queries?

Comment: And of course how a query is handled depends on quite a few things that are indeed not necessarily intuitive - for example an index on a column with to few distinct values usually leads to much worse performances, since the DB will first try to use the index, and then have to do a sequential scan on the results - which in the end can be more costly than directly going for the sequential scan.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE benchmark;   With that information, we will confirm which ENGINE is being used.

Comment: Consider replacing this line
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE BENCHMARK(ID INT)')
with
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE BENCHMARK(ID INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))')  
and you will have an index available to assist with DISTINCT.

Comment: @mitkosoft no, I have not. That seems to have been the issue. I did not realize that this would make such an impact.

Comment: @rustyx I was not aware of optimizer tracing yet, I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks! We tried to make the benchmark as minimal and reproducible as possible (which it was), and dealing with times > 2 seconds made us pretty confident that we have a "real issue" here. (which it was, in the end we did not realize that DISTINCT works extremely faster on indexed fields, which in the end seems pretty logical)

Comment: @WilsonHauck the result of the TEXT query was ENGINE=InnoDB (as expected...?). Thanks for the index suggestion, this was exactly the root cause of the error.

Comment: Great, INNODB engine is much preferred over MyISAM (and in most cases FASTER). Please get in touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having versus not having an index on `id` is likely to make a huge difference.

At some point, MySQL shifts gears -- There are multiple ways to do a `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` query:

- Have a hash in memory and count how many of each.
- Write to a temp table, sort it, then go through it counting how many distinct values
- If there is a usable index, then skip from one value to the next.

The Optimizer cannot necessarily predict the best way for a given situation, so there could be times when it fails to pick the optimal situation.  There is probably no way in the old 5.5 version (almost a decade old) to get insight into what the Optimizer chose to do.  Newer versions have `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and "Optimizer Trace".

Another issue is I/O.  Reading data from disk can slow down a query ten-fold.  However, this does not seem to be an issue since the table is rather small.  And you seem to run the query immediately after building the table; that is, the table is probably entirely cached in RAM (the buffer_pool).

I hope this adds some specifics to the Comments that say that benchmarking is difficult.

Comment: The missing index was indeed the root cause of the issue. Thanks for the insight of optimizer tracing, I'll look into that. I agree that benchmarking is difficult, but at least it was pretty reproducable, which was all I was looking for.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher - Tips on setting up Optimizer_trace:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#optimizer_trace

Comment: thanks for the link! There's a typo in your optimizer syntax on this page, closing quotation marks are missing here: _optimizer_trace = 'enabled=on_**'**; and _optimizer_trace = 'enabled=off_ **'**;. Seems to be a great compendium, I'll look into it!

Comment: @ChristianKarcher - Thanks.  I fixed them.